# Batch to copy all files in subfolders to a destination without recreating the subfolders

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, copy, robocopy, xcopy

I'm still pretty new to batch scripting, but I'm currently working on a batch file that when launched lets me select a source and destination folder from a menu. Now in my source folder, it has sub-directories with more directories in those. I'm trying to get the batch file to take any and all files in my source folder and copy them into a single folder[Destination] without recreating the folder structure so that all of the files in my sources sub-directories are nice compiled at destination.

I've tried xcopy, robocopy, and to an extent for loops. My guess is that it'll have to be done through for loops, however I'm not sure the appropriate code I should be using for this. I would like all file types to be workable with this program and not just: jpg, jpeg, png, and gif.

Thanks for the help.

```
@echo off
title File Copier
color 0a

:Menu
cls
echo Main Menu
echo ---------
echo Press 1 to copy files
echo.
echo Press 2 for information
echo.
echo Press 3 to exit
echo ---------------

set /p input=
if %input% == 1 goto 1
if %input% == 2 goto 2
if %input% == 3 goto 3
goto Menu

:1
rem Source
cls
echo Please select your source folder.
echo ---------------------------------
setlocal
set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please select your source folder:',0,0).self.path""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder=%%I"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

rem Destination
echo Please select your destination folder.
echo --------------------------------------
set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please select your destination folder:',0,0).self.path""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder2=%%I"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

rem Source/Destination Info
Set source=!folder!
Set target=!folder2!
Echo Source: %source%
Echo Destination: %target%
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:Choice
set /P c=Would you like to proceed? [Y/N]
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto Yes
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto No
goto Choice

:Yes
cls
rem echo D | xcopy %source% %target% /-y
rem robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" *.* /E
for /d %a in (%source%) do @copy %a\*.jpg %target%
for /d %a in (%source%) do @copy %a\*.png %target%
for /d %a in (%source%) do @copy %a\*.gif %target%
pause
goto Success

:No
goto 1

:Success
cls
echo The file(s) were successfully copied.
timeout /t 4 >nul
goto Menu
```

Comment: A [tag:for-loop] could look like this, `For /R "%source%" %%F In  (*.jpg,*.png,*.gif)Do Copy "%%F" "%target%"`. Just take account that the command does not cater for having more than one matching filename anywhere in `%source%` or its subdirectories.

Comment: I think I understand @Compo, so as long as the file names are all different throughout all of the source folder, the likelihood of lost copies or errors is reduced? And that link is really useful, thanks a lot @Mofi!